# Can an end-entity certificate with SHA-1 be issued by an intermediate CA that has SHA-256?

Tags: tls, certificates

Just curious - if I'm using an end-entity (leaf) certificate that has a SHA-1 signature, does that mean that ALL certificates in the chain also must use SHA-1?

Comment: The reverse is going to be a part of the migration away from SHA1 in certificates. A certificate that uses a SHA1 digest algorithm can issue a certificate that uses SHA256. Migrating to SHA256 doesn't do any good unless all intermediates are also SHA256.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can. The algorithm used for signing a certificate by the issuer is independent from the algorithm which was used to sign the issuers certificate itself.